# Cannot access manifest ulr office.JS react

Tags: reactjs, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am very new for MS Add-in. I followed the instruction to build my first Excel React add-in (ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react). I used Yo generator. I only have Office 365 online. I used "npm run start:web". I didn't make any other changes, except I added the document in config. However, an error showed that "Cannot access manifest ulr at https://127.0.0.1:3000/manifest.xml. Please ensure the url is accessible." I don't know what's wrong. I also tried a Word add-in and same error. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: What do you mean "added the document in config"? Also, what steps lead up to the error and where do you see the error?

Comment: Have you try to access the URL in any browser? Is it accessible?

Comment: @RickKirkham Dear Rick, This is what I mean "added the document in config". It is the config in package.js:   "config": {     "document": "<my file link copied from the "share button" >", ...}. After I typed "npm run start:web", a new windows was launched and then this error shows up. I am using windows 10. My current desktop office is Office 2013. I didn't install Office 365 on my desktop.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes, I tried 3 different browsers, same error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with your local server if the file can't be accessed directly in any web browser. It is clearly visible the manifest file is not accessible. As soon as you make the file public and reachable in a web browser you may try sideloading your add-in in the Office application.